# ionic v.3.20.0: FilePath plugin is not installed

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I found this issue for ionic 2 in this forum, but the solution does not work for ionic v.3.20.0.

I am following the steps outlined here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/

Installation according to given instructions. Then I add the plugin to 'app.module.ts' and then I add the code from the 'Usage' part to my ts file.

I am previewing the app with the Ionic Dev App from Google Play on my Android device (LG G4), so I can get a live reload with 'ionic serve -c'.

The error I am seeing in the console is:

> [18:56:16]  console.warn: Native: tried calling FilePath.resolveNativePath, but the FilePath plugin is not installed.> [18:56:16]  console.warn: Install the FilePath plugin: 'ionic cordova
>   plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath'
>   [18:56:16]  console.log: plugin_not_installed

Does anyone know how to deal with this error?

**Update: package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "------------",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "-------------",
  "homepage": "----------------",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/music-controls": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/streaming-media": "^4.5.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia": "~0.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "~5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "git+https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-music-controls": "^2.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-streaming-media": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "----------------------------",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media": {},
      "cordova-plugin-music-controls": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: ionic serve does not support cordova by default. Use an emulator/device

Comment: It does when previewing the app with the Ionic Dev app. All other cordova plugins are working correctly.

Comment: Did you run both commands? Show us your package.json please.

Comment: Yes, I ran both commands, and my .json looks alright, I believe. Please see update above!

Comment: I think you need to add the android platform:
ionic cordova platform add android

Comment: I tried that, but it exists: "Platform android already exists."
I tried removing and re-adding the platform, but the problem persists.
I noticed the missing "Android" from the json and added it there as well..

Comment: And if you try to run without the DevApp?
ionic cordova run android --device
Works?

Comment: Hmmm... when I do that, then the plugin 'cordova-plugin-music-controls' does not work. And that plugin is using the FilePath plugin to show an image in the music controls...  So, no, negative result! Oh, and actually none of the cordova plugins are showing up (e.g. splash screen)

Comment: Found the reason for cordova plugins not to work... I had updated my Android SDK tools few days ago, and there appears to be a bug with the latest SDK tools.  So, I downgraded that one a few versions and now the plugins are working.  HOWEVER: the orginal problem is still existing!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166915/discussion-between-humberto-de-carvalho-and-el-fred).

Comment: Ok, so I am still stuck with the same problem and the solution above did not help. I found out that once installed the plugin defines the "window.FilePath" object. How do I call this object preceeding with "window.", since my constructor uses "private filePath: FilePath"